# how to get webdav to return svn directory listing

Tags: webdav

This might be a simple question, but I am at a loss.

I am writing a small SVN web client which uses HTTP requests to Webdav api's on my Apache server.

I have been unsuccessful at finding a way to get Webdav to return a SVN directory listing like "svn list --verbose svn://mysvnrepository.com/somerepostiory/" does..

Because our server uses the svn protocol, I am not able to get the listing by navigating to "svn://mysvnrepository.com/somerepostiory/"n via the browser, etc.

Unfortunately, I wont be able to modify the server configurations for this.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with Webdav / svn?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you've tried so far, so for now I'll point you at the spec:

[RFC 4918, Section 9.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.1)